# Replaying a video continuously in a WPF media element

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, mediaelement, replay

I have a video file playing in a media element. I need to keep it playing, thus I tried:

```
me.play();
me.MediaEnded += new RoutedEventHandler(me_MediaEnded);
```

With this event method:

```
//loop to keep video playing continuously
void me_MediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //play video again
    me.Play();
}
```

However the above does not replay the video file. Why? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to a [post on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4ba7225a-5910-41da-a167-837258111974/mediaelement-repeatreplay-behaviour?forum=wpf):

> Play() starts from the current position therefore you have to first go to the starting place and then play it again.

So you have to reset the position before replaying:

```
me.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
me.Play();
```

Comment: worked for me but only after I changed LoadedBehavior to Manual

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a Storyboard to control and loop the video without needing to hook events or do any code-behind work. This is the recommended solution on MSDN and is a more elegant and proper solution for MVVM design.

Read more on MSDN here, includes examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741866%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the reason but this **never worked** for me with a GIF:

```
me.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
me.Play();
```

My GIF stops playing after the first iteration.

The solution is:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="me"
              MediaEnded="MediaElement_MediaEnded"
              LoadedBehavior="Play" />
```

Code:

```
private void MediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    me.Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
}
```

1 ms is used while 0ms might stop the playback you cannot run it again with a 'Play' method.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work with this:

```
class MyMediaPlayer : MediaPlayer
{
    private bool looping;

    public MyMediaPlayer() : base()
    {
        looping = false;  
        base.MediaEnded += new EventHandler(mediaEnded);
    }

    public MyMediaPlayer(string _file) : base()
    {
        looping = false;
        base.Open(new Uri(_file, UriKind.Relative));
        base.MediaEnded += new EventHandler(mediaEnded);
    }   

    public bool Looping
    {
        get { return looping;}
        set { looping = value; }
    }

    public void playLooping()
    {
        looping = true;
        base.Play();
    }

    public void playLooping(string _file)
    {
        looping = true;
        base.Open(new Uri(_file, UriKind.Relative));
        base.Play();
    }

    public void play()
    {
        looping = false;
        base.Play();
    }

    public void play(string _file)
    {
        looping = false;
        base.Open(new Uri(_file, UriKind.Relative));
        base.Play();
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        looping = false;
        base.Stop();
    }

    private void mediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(looping)
        {
            base.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
            base.Play();
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this answers your question.